# Fidelity API or Auto-Login Script

Tags: api, parsing, csv, login-script, autologin

I need to manage 50 accounts from Fidelity.com on a daily basis. All of these accounts are under the same person.  I'm trying to write a script to auto-login to each of these and download a CSV file that includes all positions daily (which I would then like to parse into one CSV file).  Could anyone recommend a solution or script to auto-login to Fidelity?  It doesn't look like they have an API to interface with, but I see many 3rd party solutions (ie. Mint) that can interface with this data.